# update-manager problem: Failed to download repository information

Tags: update-manager

I'm new to this forum and not a techie, but I LOVE Ubuntu and have been using it since 12.04.
Thanks to all who help here.

Since downloading 16.04, I get a "`Failed to download repository information`" message when I use the Software Updater. I did

```
update-manager -d
```

in the Terminal, and it came back with:

```
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
```

Can anyone tell me, in simple terms, what I need to do?

Thanks in anticipation.

EDIT:
Output of `sudo apt update`

```
Get:1 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB] 
Hit:2 ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:3 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Get:4 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [92.2 kB] 
Ign:5 ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:6 ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:7 ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:8 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease 
Ign:9 ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:10 ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Err:11 ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release 404 Not Found
Err:12 ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release 404 Not Found Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: If you read your error message you can see that you need to upgrade the older packages.Therefore, you must run `sudo apt-get upgrade` before you upgrade to a new distro and it will , I guess, fix your issue.

Comment: Just ignore the `PyGIWarning`. they appeared, because `GObjectIntrospection` was updated.

Answer (score 0):

To update your system just run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: The commands should be `apt-get`, rather than just `apt`

Comment: From 16.04 apt-get is beeing replaced with the newest apt. Both are fully working but apt-get will be deprecated soon. [link](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/)

Comment: I'd not realised, though the link appears to suggest that `apt-upgrade` is the same as `apt-get dist-upgrade` so perhaps the last two commands do the same thing?

Comment: :) Thanks for your help. The Software updater still says "Failed to download repository information" though. :/

Comment: Shortly the upgrade version only upgrades existing packages while dist-upgrade manage the addiction or removal of packages. See  man apt-get for more accurate info.

Comment: Post the output of the sudo apt update command

Comment: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [92.2 kB]   
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Comment: Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found

Comment: Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: try with
`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
`sudo ppa-purge ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu`
`sudo apt update`

Comment: Still get the same message (sorry).  The terminal gave: "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases'
E: Unable to locate package update"

Comment: Try to remove the `ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases` and `ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu` ppas using [this](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-remove-ppa-include-installed-packages-in-ubuntu) guide

Comment: Meh! :(  First I tired to remove the ppas, as per no.1. Then I removed Handbrake and Musescore using Ubuntu Software, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @velix I don't think `apt-get` is being deprecated. http://askubuntu.com/questions/762351/are-apt-get-commands-being-phased-out . Also `apt` commands do not map exactly to 'apt-get' commands so your explanation in the previous comment doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: @Arronical I just wanted to say that from 16.04, Ubuntu suggests the use of apt instead of apt-get. The man page for apt can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html). Anyway update, upgrade, install, remove, purge, and autoremove work the same with both apt & apt-get.

Comment: @user534936 Has something changed with the error? Or is it the same? Remember to post the error, if changed, every time you made an attemp to resolve it.

Comment: Oh! My apologies - I'm not au fait with the system yet.

Comment: Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [92.2 kB]   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease

Comment: Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB]    
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [5,404 B]

Comment: Get:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [2,828 B]
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [3,312 B]
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [2,440 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [2,924 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [1,288 B]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [1,084 B]

Comment: Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [684 B]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Would it be easiest just to flash Ubuntu again?

Comment: It depends on you. Howeer if you have correctly removed those ppas you shouldn't see those errors anymore. Please post the output of `more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: *** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/: directory ***

Comment: Sorry my fault. The command should be `sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: You're all very kind to help me like this.

Comment: dhor-ubuntu-myway-xenial.list
dhor-ubuntu-myway-xenial.list.save
mscore-ubuntu-ubuntu-mscore-stable-xenial.list
mscore-ubuntu-ubuntu-mscore-stable-xenial.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list.save
rebuntu16-ubuntu-avidemux_unofficial-xenial.list
rebuntu16-ubuntu-avidemux_unofficial-xenial.list.save
stebbins-ubuntu-handbrake-releases-xenial.list
stebbins-ubuntu-handbrake-releases-xenial.list.save
webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-xenial.list
webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-xenial.list.save

Comment: Avidemux didn't download. I've removed Musescore and handbrake using the Ubuntu store. The only thing left is the tor browser. That didn't give any problems in 14.04.  Should I remove it too?

Comment: ppas are still there... Try running `cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d /home/sources.list.d.back`
`sudo rm -rf mscore-ubuntu-ubuntu-mscore-stable*`
`sudo rm -rf stebbins-ubuntu-handbrake-releases*`
Post again the result of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [92.2 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Comment: Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease    
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Are you sure to have executed the ppa-purge command? Try `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu ` and `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu`

Comment: :$ I hope I've followed all the instructions carefully. I've just done sudo ppa-purge ppa:ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu, but it's come back with: sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

Comment: Use `sudo apt install ppa-purge` and retry

Comment: Ooh! The install purge did something!

Comment: then I ran :~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: The 2nd one gave: Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: Very strange... The ppa-purge program should have resolved anything. Post the output of  `more /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20160420.1)]/ xenia
l main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

Comment: deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.

Comment: deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
--More--(47%)

Comment: I think I'd better start over...

Comment: You've not posted the entire output. Try running again the command and go on with the spacebar, or use `less /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted univer
se multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted 
universe multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

Comment: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

Comment: (It was still in the Terminal)

Comment: Please run `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/`
`sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw/GdQqiFwY" -O /etc/apt/sources.list`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list`
`sudo apt-get update `

Comment: Okay - I've done that...

Comment: running sudo apt update now gives: Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release

Comment: 404  Not Found Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [92.2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Okay - Thanks for all the help.  A day on this is enough - I'm going to reflash (and not go anywhere near Handbrake and Musescore for a while!)