# Are apt-get commands being phased out?

Tags: apt, package-management

It is now possible to use `apt` commands alongside `apt-get` commands within Ubuntu. In an attempt to answer a question on Ask Ubuntu I was informed that `apt-get` will soon become deprecated.

Is this true, and is there any official timeline for the phasing out of `apt-get`?

Comment: I don't think they are getting rid of `apt-get` any time soon.

Comment: As far as I know there is no timeline for that. For compatibility reasons it should work for a substantial amount of time

Comment: Looking at the APT man page, it looks like apt-get is going to stay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Soon" is a strange concept in something with supported releases, like Ubuntu.
16.04 is supported into 2020 so `apt-get` will be around as a primary tool at least until then.

As pure conjecture, it *might* be relegated to an alias (or something like that) *one day* but getting rid of it completely could cause significant scripting issues. A complete change of package manager seems just as likely.

So at this point in time, I'd be asking anybody spouting "omg it's deprecated" to cite their source. Or explain what they mean by deprecated.